# Automorphisms of group $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't know if $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_8)$ is a cyclic group. I do know that an automorphism is a isomorphism that sends an element of a group to itself (i.e) $f:G\to G$ and a cyclic means that for any element $g\in G$, $\exists m$ (least m by Well-Ordering Property) such that $g^m=g$. I just do not know how to put these information together to know if $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_8)}$ is cyclic.

Comment: Can you find an element of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_8)$?

Comment: 3? Since $Aut{(\mathbb{Z_8}) : \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\rightarrow \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

Comment: An example of an automorphism f: G->G might be something like f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=3, etc up to f(7)=0

Comment: Your definition of "cyclic" is astray.You really need to sort that out first.

Comment: Your example is not an automorphism. Automorphisms send $0$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of cyclic group is slightly off. A group $G$ is cyclic means that there is some element $x \in G$ such that every element $y \in G$ has the form $y = x^m$ for some integer $m$.

Now, there aren't *that* many automorphisms in your group. You can write them all out. Here's a hint: Where can an automorphism take 1? It can't go to 4, because if f is a homomorphism with $f(1) = 4,$ then $f(1 + 1) = 4 + 4 = 0 = f(0)$ so $f$ isn't injective.  Once you write out explicitly all the members of your group, this question is should be apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_n^*$. What is $\mathbb{Z}_8^*$?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Do you see why $f(n) = 3n$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_8$?